# How to apply dunn.test for dataframes in R?

Tags: r, controls, kruskal-wallis, dunn.test

I have a CSV file with two columns: group and weight.
I'm able to do a Kruskal–Wallis test:

```
kruskal.test(Weight~Group, data=Data.df)
```

I want to calculate pairwise multiple comparisons with the control group (there are different treatments). I have tried `dunn.test.control`, but I only get errors. I don't think I'm using the command correctly.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Feel free to show an example!

Comment: Feel free to show us an example of your data ))) You can use `dput()` for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get a better response if you include some data (or illustrate your issue using data already available in R (see `data()`), show the code that was not working and the error message(s), and indicate what package the function giving you trouble comes from since `dunn.test.control` is not included with R but in the `PMCMR` package. For example, we can use the `iris` data set included in R (`?iris` for info):

```
kruskal.test(Sepal.Width~Species, iris)
#
#   Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
#
# data:  Sepal.Width by Species
# Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 63.571, df = 2, p-value = 1.569e-14
```

Shows that there is a significant difference. Now the Dunn test:

```
library(PMCMR)
dunn.test.control(iris$Sepal.Width, iris$Species)
#
#   Pairwise comparisons using Dunn's-test for multiple 
#                         comparisons with one control
#
# data: iris$Sepal.Width and iris$Species
#
#           setosa 
# versicolor 1.4e-14
# virginica  7.7e-08
```

No error message so you probably did not specify the test correctly. But this is not a pairwise test. You probably want

```
posthoc.kruskal.dunn.test(iris$Sepal.Width, iris$Species)
# 
#   Pairwise comparisons using Dunn's-test for multiple 
#                          comparisons of independent samples
# 
# data: iris$Sepal.Width and iris$Species
# 
#            setosa  versicolor
# versicolor 2.0e-14 -         
# virginica  1.5e-07 0.016     
# 
# P value adjustment method: holm
# Warning message:
# In posthoc.kruskal.dunn.test.default(iris$Sepal.Width, iris$Species) :
#   Ties are present. z-quantiles were corrected for ties.
```

Notice the warning message. The test runs, but exact probabilities cannot be computed because there are tied ranks. Two of the comparisons are so small that ties are not a factor unless your sample size is small. I prefer the version of the test in `DescTools` since it also shows the mean rank difference between each pair:

```
library(DescTools)
DunnTest(Sepal.Width~Species, iris)
# 
#  Dunn's test of multiple comparisons using rank sums : holm  
# 
#                      mean.rank.diff    pval    
# versicolor-setosa            -67.38 2.0e-14 ***
# virginica-setosa             -46.50 1.5e-07 ***
# virginica-versicolor          20.88  0.0158 *  
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```